# Comunicación entre funciones de distintos componentes (React Js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

En React se puede, por ejemplo, desde un componente llamado "Navegador" llamar a la función de otro componente y de esta manera al hacer click en algún elemento del navegador, utilizar la función que definido en este segundo componente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede. Uno de los [principios de diseño](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/design-principles.html#composition) de React es la composición de componentes, la cual permite agregar funcionalidad a un componente, por ejemplo el [paso de funciones a componentes](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html).

Ahi va un ejemplo basado en tu descripción:

```js
function Navegador({ handleClick }) {
  // handleClick viene como 'prop' desde el componente <App />
  return(
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>Productos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}



class App extends React.Component {

  // La funcion handleClick nos muestra el texto del elemento clickeado

  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(`Hiciste click en un link en ${e.target.innerText}`)
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {/* Aquí pasamos la funcion al componente hijo */}
        <Navegador handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <p>Esta es seccion principal de la app</p>
      </div>
    )

  }

}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Cabe aclarar que `<App>` es un componente clase y `<Navegador>` es un componente funcional. En la [documentación oficial](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) puedes aprender mas sobre las diferencias de cada uno y cuando utilizarlos.

Comment: Genial, muchísimas gracias por el aporte!!

Answer (score 3):

En React puedes tener un componente **Padre** que contenga una serie de componentes diferentes, en este componente puedes declarar una función que los componentes adscritos a **Padre** pueden usar si tú lo colocas como atributo, por ejemplo:

```
<Hijo1 funcion={this.funcion_padre} />
```

`<Hijo1>` sería uno de los componentes adscritos a Padre y la función pasaría en las props de **Hijo1**, así puedes hacer uso de ella dentro de **Hijo1**.

Espero haberte ayudado.